# When I open another app on my android I receive Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: android, sigabrt, android-anr-dialog

My app opens a png image. When I send to print, my application stop and my console (logcat) just show the message:

```
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13555 (RenderThread)
```

In the tablet screen it shows: Application Not Responding (ANR).

I can print the image, but my app stop and I need to restart the session.

I'm looking for a solution.

Some code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.imprimir) {
            Bitmap bitmap = Util.screenShot(mWebView);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "screenshot.png");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/png");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: it really wouldn't hurt to see some code

Comment: Try doing all of that work on a background thread instead of the UI thread, so that you don't get the ANR